# Translate a DLL call from PowerBasic to Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, spss

I would like to call SPSS 'backend' from Delphi. There is a DLL that I can use (it seems): `SPSSio64.DLL`. But I can not find the interface definition.

What I have found is an example in PowerBasic:

[Read and write SPSS sav files](https://forum.powerbasic.com/forum/user-to-user-discussions/source-code/44179-read-and-write-spss-sav-files)

```
DECLARE FUNCTION spssOpenRead LIB "spssio32.dll" ALIAS "spssOpenRead@8" (BYVAL fileName AS STRING, BYREF hHandle AS LONG) AS LONG
DECLARE FUNCTION spssCloseRead LIB "spssio32.dll" ALIAS "spssCloseRead@4" (BYVAL hHandle AS LONG) AS LONG
```

Since I only need functions to read and write a file (all the processing will be done via a syntax in that file), I thought that this example might be enough to deduce how to call equivalent functions from Delphi.

So the question is: how would these declarations be in Delphi (64-bit)?

Comment: This is all documented. Try to do it yourself.

Comment: Note that you want to use spssio64.dll, but the examples are for spssio32.dll.

Comment: It must be easy when you are an expert. When you are not, and you don't know where to start or how to ask, frustration lures. Rudy: thanks; David: a pointer would be great.

Comment: I suggest you do some research and read some docs. It feels as though you just want to be provided with code. How will that help you learn. And what value will this question have for others. You now have an answer which provides no teaching or explanation, just code. It depresses me. Nobody becomes an expert by blindly copying code. And yes, it is easy when you are an expert. Wouldn't you like to become expert?

Comment: Correct. I am an expert but in a completely different field. When you need to change the lock on a back door of the nuclear plant you're building, there's no need to learn - but to get someone who knows how to change the lock. I'm always pleased to help others. We should'nt have discussions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this works:

```
function LoadDLL(DLLname : string) : Uint64;
var
  em : TArithmeticExceptionMask;
begin
  em:=GetExceptionmask;
  SetExceptionmask(em+[exInvalidOp,exZeroDivide,exOverflow,exUnderflow]);
  result:=LoadLibrary(PwideChar(DLLname));
  SetExceptionmask(em);
end;

function RunSPSSio(filename : string; instructions : Tinstructions) : boolean;
// This will only read SAV files, not SPS files !
type
  TspssOpenRead             = function (filename: PAnsiChar; var hHandle: Uint64): Integer;
  TspssCloseRead            = function(hHandle: Uint64): Integer;
  TspssGetInterfaceEncoding = function(hHandle : Uint64): Integer;
  TspssSetInterfaceEncoding = function(encoding : integer; hHandle : Uint64): Integer;
const
  SPSS_ENCODING_UTF8     = 1;
var
  p                      : integer;
  spssOpenRead           : TspssOpenRead;
  spssCloseRead          : TspssCloseRead;
  spssGetIFencoding      : TspssGetInterfaceEncoding;
  spssSetIFencoding      : TspssSetInterfaceEncoding;
  DLLhandle              : Uint64;
  fileref                : PANSIchar;
begin
  result:=false;
  DLLhandle:=LoadDLL('C:\SPSS\spssio64.dll'); // hardcoded
  if DLLhandle=0
     then begin p:=GetLastError();
                report('DLL load error '+IntToStr(p));
                exit;
          end;
  try
    @SPSSopenRead:=getProcAddress(DLLhandle,'spssOpenRead');
    @SPSScloseRead:=getProcAddress(DLLhandle,'spssCloseRead');

    @SPSSsetIFencoding:=getProcAddress(DLLhandle,'spssSetInterfaceEncoding');
    SPSSsetIFencoding(SPSS_ENCODING_UTF8,DLLhandle);

    fileref:=PANSIchar(ANSIstring(filename));
    p:=SPSSopenRead(fileref,DLLhandle);
    if p<>0
       then report('*** SPSSio error '+IntToStr(p))
       else begin // SPSS database interactions here
                  result:=SPSScloseRead(DLLhandle)=0;
            end;
  finally
    freeLibrary(DLLhandle);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [SPSS 14.0 for Windows Developer's Guide](https://www.scribd.com/document/397157/SPSS-14-0-for-Windows-Developer-s-Guide), and [PowerBasic documentation](https://www.powerbasic.com/help/pbcc/), try something like this:

32-bit:

```
// spssio32.dll exports both 'spssOpenRead' and 'spssOpenRead@8', which are the same function...
function spssOpenRead(filename: PAnsiChar; var hHandle: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'spssio32.dll' {name 'spssOpenRead@8'};

// spssio32.dll exports both 'spssCloseRead' and 'spssCloseRead@4', which are the same function...
function spssCloseRead(hHandle: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'spssio32.dll' {name 'spssCloseRead@4'};
```

64-bit:

```
// I can't find a copy of spssio64.dll to download, so I can't verify the exported names. Adjust if needed..

function spssOpenRead(filename: PAnsiChar; var hHandle: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'spssio64.dll' {name 'spssOpenRead@16'};

function spssCloseRead(hHandle: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'spssio64.dll' {name 'spssCloseRead@8'};
```

Comment: IBM was so kind to send full documentation of SPSSio64. The names are correct. The calls work.